# Require error, but file exists

Tags: php, error-handling, structure, require

I have this code:

```
require_once('../core.php');
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../core.php' (include_path='.;D:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Nytrix\php\login\register.php on line 2

but here is a picture of my file structure and it is actually there: http://prntscr.com/52oc7q

So my question is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you access it with the full path? It may be that your PHP include path is not what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your inclusion path is different.

You can provide the path of core.php relative to the base path (where the main index.php file is being executed).